# What is the meaning of 出来が違い?

Tags: meaning

> どうせ兄貴とは出来が違いまさぁ

I tried to look it up but to no avail !  but i guess it means that the speaker think he is different than his brother ,right?

Comment: Do you mean you couldn't find a definition of 出来? Or you could, but you couldn't understand what you found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look up the meaning of 出来が違う, not 出来が違い. (違う is a godan verb, and [まさぁ](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%95%E3%81%82) is a stronger and dialectal variant of ます.)

出来が違う is a set phrase that means someone is congenitally, developmentally or inherently different. This 出来 means "quality (of a product, crop, child development, etc)". For example we say 彼は頭の出来が違う to describe a natural-born genius. Your sentence means 兄貴 has been talented (for something) since he was born or young.